# How to convert data in one row with many row into one row with many column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert data into this format like. I want to convert the data into this format like.Please Somebody help me. I'm looking for an efficient way to convert data into this format like. I want to convert the data into this format like.Please Somebody help me.
This is my result:.Hi i have data like this in sql

```
Jan  Feb  March  Apr  May  Jun  July
1     2     3      1    4   8   9
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert data into this format like. I want to convert the data into this format like.Please Somebody help me. I'm looking for an efficient way to convert data into this format like. I want to convert the data into this format like.Please Somebody help me.
This is my result:

```
Month   Count
Jan     1
Feb     2
March   3
Apr     1
May     4
Jun     8   
July    9
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert data into this format like. I want to convert the data into this format like.Please Somebody help me.
This is my result:

Comment: MySQL? SQL Server? SQLite?

Comment: Your table contains only one row with seven columns and you want to output seven rows instead? Yes? And you are using three different database systems (MySQL, SQL Server *and* SQLite)???

Comment: Use UNPIVOT , search for the examples ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $r=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from your_table limit 1")));
    if($r)foreach($r as $k=>$v){
       $rr= mysql_query("insert into target_table(collumn_name1,collumn_name2) values ('$k','$v')");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #Table_1
(
   Jan Int,
   Feb Int,
   March Int,
   Apr Int,
   May Int,
   Jun Int,
   July Int
)
insert into #Table_1 values(1,2,3,1,4,8,9)
select * from #Table_1

select [Month], [Count] from #Table_1
Unpivot
(
  [Count] for [Month] in ([Jan],[Feb],[March],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[July])

) as UnPvt
```